# AFNetworking: Dispatching a concurrent queue and running synchronous tasks within that

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` in an app I am developing. For downloading requests, I am ussing `AFHTTPRequestOperation`'s `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure`. This ties a success block and and a failure block to an `operation`, and the operation is then added to an `NSOperationQueue` using `addOperation`.

`AFNetworking` creates an asynchronous thread and runs all the data there. However, I'd like to add three operations to a concurrent thread, whereby they run synchronously. Also known as a `serial queue` in GCD. How can I achieve that in `AFNetworking`? Should I create my own serial queue and then `addOperation` in that queue, moving all the request initialization, success block, failure block and adding under the serial queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `NSOperationQueue` `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property to 1 effectively creates a serial queue. You can then be assured each request will complete before the next operation is triggered.